# Calling a ActiveX Control from within a C# Windows application

Tags: c#, activex

I have a requirement to have an event that calls an ActiveX control from within a C# desktop application and am not sure if this is possible firstly. The second problem is theoretically how is this achieved, is the ActiveX control a dll that is referenced or is it a remote executable? Or does this depend upon the ActiveX control?

If someone could help steer me in the right direction and provide a link to reference that would be great.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS, You can drag and drop activeX control on `ToolBox` pan, and then use it like other controls on toolbox. first be sure you done `regsvr32 myactivex.ocx` before.

Comment: Thanks so can I take it that an ActiveX control has to be local and is not something that can be run remotely from my application to a remote server that has the ActiveX control residing?

Comment: @aHunter, In general, It's local, but you can call it from server side and load it in client side, like other objects, If you do what I said, you can see how to initiate it in your form (by auto generated code). and you can do it without drag and drop yourself.

Comment: @aHunter, for example too many web pages using some activex and they try to install them in your PC to show you a good view, they all will be loaded in client side.